# Spreading character string into multiple columns with strsplit pattern matching

Tags: r, regex, strsplit, tibble

This is my first time **scraping** text from a PDF document. I'm presenting what I think is the most useful format for the data for what I'm doing, but I could be wrong. Once I cleaned the PDF text, I formatted it into a `tibble` (below).

I tried utilizing `strsplit(dmt, \\s+)` to split the character string into three separate columns but that just separated everything completely. I had used `str_squish()` to eliminate the spaces in the middle text portion of the string but that did not help the pattern matching.

The first numeric part of the character string sometimes ends with a `)` or a `number`.  Here is what I'm working with:

```
dmt
# A tibble: 612 x 1
   datamatrixtest[,1]                                             
   <chr>                                                          
 1 110.05          Human Service Vehicle Inspection Reqd         6
 2 23.33(12)(b)    ATV-Fail/Stop for Law Enforce. Official       1
 3 23.33(6)(a)     ATV-Fail/Display Lighted Headlamp             1
 4 341.03          Oper Veh After Sus/Rev or Can of Reg      8,862
 5 341.04(1)       Non-Registration of Vehicle              10,125
 6 341.04(2)       Improper Registration of Vehicle              4
 7 341.15(1)       Fail/Display Vehicle License Plates       2,010
 8 341.15(1m)(a)   Fail/Attach Rear Regis. Decal/Tag             3
 9 341.15(1m)(b)   Fail/Attach Front Regis. Decal/Tag            2
10 341.15(2)       Improperly Attached License Plates            7
# ... with 602 more rows
```

Ideally, I could utilize `strsplit` with an accurate pattern match to put the data into three separate columns.

```
dmt
# A tibble: 612 x 3
   statute         offense                                    cases
   <chr>           <chr>                                       <num>        
 1 110.05          Human Service Vehicle Inspection Reqd         6
 2 23.33(12)(b)    ATV-Fail/Stop for Law Enforce. Official       1
 3 23.33(6)(a)     ATV-Fail/Display Lighted Headlamp             1
 4 341.03          Oper Veh After Sus/Rev or Can of Reg      8,862
 5 341.04(1)       Non-Registration of Vehicle              10,125
 6 341.04(2)       Improper Registration of Vehicle              4
 7 341.15(1)       Fail/Display Vehicle License Plates       2,010
 8 341.15(1m)(a)   Fail/Attach Rear Regis. Decal/Tag             3
 9 341.15(1m)(b)   Fail/Attach Front Regis. Decal/Tag            2
10 341.15(2)       Improperly Attached License Plates            7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your data is essentially as presented, with multiple spaces between columns. In other words, check that your `dmt` is comparable to the one I've created below. In that case, we can just split each line on any section of more than one space with `\\s{2,}` like this. If your data is not like this, or if any individual field happens to contain multiple spaces, then use `dput` and `head` to provide a sample so we can find a more precise pattern that will work.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dmt <- read_lines(
"110.05          Human Service Vehicle Inspection Reqd         6
23.33(12)(b)    ATV-Fail/Stop for Law Enforce. Official       1
23.33(6)(a)     ATV-Fail/Display Lighted Headlamp             1
341.03          Oper Veh After Sus/Rev or Can of Reg      8,862
341.04(1)       Non-Registration of Vehicle              10,125
341.04(2)       Improper Registration of Vehicle              4
341.15(1)       Fail/Display Vehicle License Plates       2,010
341.15(1m)(a)   Fail/Attach Rear Regis. Decal/Tag             3
341.15(1m)(b)   Fail/Attach Front Regis. Decal/Tag            2
1341.15(2)       Improperly Attached License Plates            7"
) %>%
  enframe(name = NULL, value = "line")

dmt %>%
  separate(line, c("statute", "offense", "cases"), sep = "\\s{2,}") %>%
  mutate(cases = cases %>% str_remove_all(",") %>% as.integer)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    statute       offense                                 cases
#>    <chr>         <chr>                                   <int>
#>  1 110.05        Human Service Vehicle Inspection Reqd       6
#>  2 23.33(12)(b)  ATV-Fail/Stop for Law Enforce. Official     1
#>  3 23.33(6)(a)   ATV-Fail/Display Lighted Headlamp           1
#>  4 341.03        Oper Veh After Sus/Rev or Can of Reg     8862
#>  5 341.04(1)     Non-Registration of Vehicle             10125
#>  6 341.04(2)     Improper Registration of Vehicle            4
#>  7 341.15(1)     Fail/Display Vehicle License Plates      2010
#>  8 341.15(1m)(a) Fail/Attach Rear Regis. Decal/Tag           3
#>  9 341.15(1m)(b) Fail/Attach Front Regis. Decal/Tag          2
#> 10 1341.15(2)    Improperly Attached License Plates          7
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I had to add the `enframe(name = NULL, value = "line")` to my pipe to format my data, but once I did that it worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your data, we can also use `tidyr::extract` by defining different capture groups.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   extract(datamatrixtest, into = c("statute", "offense", "cases"),
           regex = "(.*?)\\s(.*?)(\\d.*)") %>%
    mutate_all(trimws)


#   statute       offense                                 cases 
#   <chr>         <chr>                                   <chr> 
# 1 110.05        Human Service Vehicle Inspection Reqd   6     
# 2 23.33(12)(b)  ATV-Fail/Stop for Law Enforce. Official 1     
# 3 23.33(6)(a)   ATV-Fail/Display Lighted Headlamp       1     
# 4 341.03        Oper Veh After Sus/Rev or Can of Reg    8,862 
# 5 341.04(1)     Non-Registration of Vehicle             10,125
# 6 341.04(2)     Improper Registration of Vehicle        4     
# 7 341.15(1)     Fail/Display Vehicle License Plates     2,010 
# 8 341.15(1m)(a) Fail/Attach Rear Regis. Decal/Tag       3     
# 9 341.15(1m)(b) Fail/Attach Front Regis. Decal/Tag      2     
#10 1341.15(2)    Improperly Attached License Plates      7
```

Here, we define three groups, first starts from beginning of the text till the first whitespace is encountered, second one starts from where the first one ends till a number is encountered and the third one takes everything from the number till the end of the sentence.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(datamatrixtest = c("110.05          Human Service 
Vehicle Inspection Reqd         6", 
"23.33(12)(b)    ATV-Fail/Stop for Law Enforce. Official       1", 
"23.33(6)(a)     ATV-Fail/Display Lighted Headlamp             1", 
"341.03          Oper Veh After Sus/Rev or Can of Reg      8,862", 
"341.04(1)       Non-Registration of Vehicle              10,125", 
"341.04(2)       Improper Registration of Vehicle              4", 
"341.15(1)       Fail/Display Vehicle License Plates       2,010", 
"341.15(1m)(a)   Fail/Attach Rear Regis. Decal/Tag             3", 
"341.15(1m)(b)   Fail/Attach Front Regis. Decal/Tag            2", 
"1341.15(2)       Improperly Attached License Plates            7"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: i realized looking at these solutions that i needed to specify/create the new columns as part of my processing of the string. The `regex` is really helpful. Thank you.